# Postfix issue on Mac OS X 10.12.6

Tags: macos, email

I'm using Postfix to forward emails from my Mac through smtp.gmail.com.

Following recent security update (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208221) Postfix fails to forward emails with the following errors:

```
smtp: warning: Digest algorithm "md5" not found
smtp: warning: disabling TLS support
smtp: TLS is required, but our TLS engine is unavailable
```

Here is a snippet from Postfix main.cf.

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

Any ideas how to get this working again?

Comment: Same issue posted on Stackoverflow... no comments yet -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111296/mac-os-x-10-12-6-sierra-smtp-digest-algorithm-md5-not-found-disabling-tls-su

Comment: @BenL please note that upgrade to High Sierra (10.13.1) fixed the issue for me without any configuration changes.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. I will upgrade as soon as I am ready to tackle the rebuilding of my dev environment that an OS upgrade will entail.

Answer (score 1):

I also upgraded to High Sierra and that fixed the issue for me. I have been trying for a week to find a solution.

Comment: Upgrading to High Sierra also fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I'm on Sierra, heard bad things about High Sierra, any solution that doesn't involve upgrading to High Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

I got postfix working again on Sierra by installing (and configuring) postfix from macports.  Upgrading to High Sierra is currently not a solution for me because my system disk is an AppleRAID.

Comment: Can you PLEASE explain exactly what you did? I have tried installing postfix from macports and I got the same error.

Comment: Looking at my .sh_history, it looks like I just followed the instructions on [this page](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/SetupPostfix).

Comment: Also, I think you have to run the following commands:

    $ sudo port load postfix
    $ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist

Comment: # A startup item has been generated that will aid in
# starting postfix with launchd. It is disabled
# by default. Execute the following command to start it,
# and to cause it to launch at startup:
#
# sudo port load postfix
...
  postfix has the following notes:
    To get postfix working, you need to edit the configuration files (/opt/local/etc/postfix/*). You may also want to turn off Apple's built-in MTA. For example:

    sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist

Comment: LIFESAVER! I think that command is the solution. Will try tomorrow. I have littlerly been trying to get enough points to comment just to comment on this post. Thanks!

Comment: Can your paste you main.cf here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412895/how-to-fix-postfix-on-macos-sierra-10-12-6?rq=1 please?